# Using console while editing a file in mc no longer possible?

Tags: console, mc

I used to open a file for editing in `mc` (using `mcedit` to be more exact) and then switch to console to do some stuff, then again return to file editing and so on.

Some time ago (after updating `mc` I suppose) things changed and now should I switch to console via `ctrl-o` while editing a file and start typing a console command, it returns me back to my file and puts everything typed to it. It used to stay in console until I specifically return to my file via `ctrl-o`.

Why is it happening like so now, what changed? Is there any setting to revert it back?

Comment: the version you are now (and then) may be useful in answering

Comment: @WEBjuju I would mention it, if I knew. I mean I didn't notice the exact version when this behaviour changed as I don't use console every time I edit a file, so it might be a couple of updates ago actually.